# how to iterates a hashmap, does it need to cast the keySet() in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

I have a question about iterate a hashmap:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I want to iterate this hashmap and printout out the key and value pair using the following code:

```
Iterator iterator = portMap.keySet().iterator();
```

but it indicates me to cast the `portMap.keySet().iterator();` to `(Iterator)portMap.keySet().iterator()`;, but the `iterator()` return as a iterator already, why I need to cast it? And I checked some other code, there is no cast for the return value of `iterator()`, what is the reason, and how to fix it?

Comment: is it intentional that `map` and `portMap` are different?

Comment: Is there any errors? I guess your IDE would just be showing a warning (yellow underline in eclipse), that's because whats returned could be Iterator<String> and you are assigning it to Iterator

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print the keys AND the values, you should use `entrySet` instead:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue());
}
```

As for your casting issue, it may be because you are importing a different Iterator class in your imports. With the correct imports, this compiles fine without casting:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

//.....

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
```

Comment: why iterator should be inported then?

Comment: @ratzip i think you mean "what" and not "why"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enhanced loop` in the following way:

```
for (Entry entry :  map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s , %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

so like this you loop over all entries of the map. 
In the import section you should have the following import of the [Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

hence the complete imports section would look like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

If you want to go over the keys and extract the corresponding value for each of them you can go the following way:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
// ...
for (String s : map.keySet()) {
   System.out.format("%s , %s\n", s, map.get(s));
}
```

If you want to use an iterator and loop over the keys and extracting from the map based on the key:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
//...

Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()){
   String currentKey = it.next();
   System.out.format("%s , %s\n", currentKey), map.get(currentKey));
}
```

I hope these help you.